# Do I have use of Chef if I'm using Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, chef-infra

I use Heroku to deploy my Rails apps.

But I thought about learning Chef to automatically set up the development infrastructure, but Im not sure.

So to put it very simple, are there any reasons for me to learn Chef?

Comment: Do you mean Engine Yard Cloud? It is a competitor to Heroku for some times of apps/budgets, and uses Chef for things like making builds of custom C libraries repeatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Heroku, no, there's no need. You are later probably going to be deploying to your own servers, so look into that; in that case, Chef might be a good option, also look at Capistrano.

Comment: Capistrano isn't built for deploying servers. It is for deploying applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how chef and heroku are related. If you're using heroku then you don't need to use chef whether it's worth learning or not is independent of your use of heroku